# How to properly dispose of SP objects although not assigned?

Tags: spweb, dispose

If I assign SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb().Title to a string, do I need to dispose of it (if possible)?

string title = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb().Title;

I'm still a little fuzzy on when to dispose of sp objects, so I always dispose of my SPWeb and SPSite objects... But, if I don't assign the statement above to an object first, is there any disposing I need to do? I also understand that there are certain cases where using Current eliminates the need to dispose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very important topic that is covered well in the following resources:

- [Best Practices: Using Disposable Windows SharePoint Services Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms778813.aspx)
- [SharePoint Dispose Checker Tool](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck)